# Trying to retrieve mails from Microsoft Graph using Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am doing a project at school where we are using `java` and `javafx`, and we need to retrieve mails from Microsoft Graph API. I have been trying to retrieve these unsuccessfully by using [Apache HttpClient](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.3).

All it returns is response code `200` but absolutely no actual content.

```
String url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages";
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
// add request header
request.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.addHeader("charset", "utf-8");
request.addHeader("Authorization", String.format("Bearer %s", "token"));

HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

System.out.println("Response Code : "
                + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()); //Response Code : 200

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent())); //No-content, even when returning response code 200????

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
}
System.out.println(line); //null
```

This would print out:

```
Response Code : 200
null
```

About the authentication I am sending the user to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
using a WebView in javafx. After the user is directed to my fake url i make a POST request to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token to acquire the token.

```
WebEngine webEngine = loginView.getEngine(); //the webview variable loginView
    webEngine.load("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=client_id&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost:0%2Fauthorize.html&response_type=code&scope=mail.read");
    webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observable, Worker.State oldValue, Worker.State newValue) {
            String url = webEngine.getLocation();
            System.out.println(url);
            String[] paths = url.split("\\?");
            if (paths[0].equals("http://localhost:0/authorize.html")) {
                try {
                    String[] para = paths[1].split("\\&");
                    String[] authcodePara = para[0].split("\\=");
                    String authcode = authcodePara[1];
                    String clientId = "client_id";
                    String clientSecret = "client_secret";
                    String redirectUrl = "http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost:0%2Fauthorize.html";
                    String grantType = "authorization_code";
                    String rawData = 
                            "grant_type=" + grantType
                            + "&" + "client_id=" + clientId
                            + "&" + "client_secret=" + clientSecret
                            + "&" + "redirect_uri=" + redirectUrl
                            + "&" + "code=" + authcode;
                    byte[] postData = rawData.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
                    int postDataLength = postData.length;
                    String request = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token";
                    URL urlTest = new URL( request );
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) urlTest.openConnection();           
                    con.setDoOutput(true);
                    con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
                    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
                    con.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
                    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postDataLength ));
                    con.setUseCaches(false);
                    try(DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream())) {
                       wr.write( postData );
                    }
                    InputStream _is;
                    if (con.getResponseCode() < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
                        _is = con.getInputStream();
                    } else {
                         /* error from server */
                        _is = con.getErrorStream();
                    }
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_is));
                    String inputLine;
                    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                            response.append(inputLine);
                    }
                    in.close();

                    //print result
                    System.out.println(response.toString()); // prints out the json data with the token.
                } catch (ProtocolException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(OutlookWebmailController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(OutlookWebmailController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

If anybody can point me in some direction on what might be the problem that would be lovely!

## Update 1

So i have tried with a simple HttpURLConnection. Here is my setup:

```
String url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages";
    URL request_url = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection http_conn = (HttpURLConnection)request_url.openConnection();
    http_conn.setConnectTimeout(100000);
    http_conn.setReadTimeout(100000);
    http_conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
    http_conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    http_conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
    http_conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", String.format("Bearer %s", "token"));
    http_conn.connect();
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(http_conn.getResponseCode()));

    InputStream _is;
    if (http_conn.getResponseCode() < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
        _is = http_conn.getInputStream();
    } else {
        /* error from server */
        _is = http_conn.getErrorStream();
    }
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_is));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());
```

This returns the following:

```
200
<data>
```

Which works! buuuut, why does it not accept the Apache HttpClient request?

Comment: Are you able to see any `messages` using [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur yes, both without and with loggin in. Forgot to mention that my registered application require these permissions: Mail.Read, Mail.Read.Shared, User.Read and when loggin i am using the scope Mail.Read

Comment: How are you obtaining your bearer token? Specifically, which OAUTH grant flow are you leveraging?

Comment: Hello @MarcLaFleur sorry for the delayed response. I have updated the question with code i am using to obtain the token.